# What is the identifier use for textbox in masm32 assembly language?

Tags: assembly, textbox, uniqueidentifier, masm32

I am following a lessons in a pdf called [winasmtut.pdf](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxjY3JldmVuZ2NjfGd4OjUwMzgyMjVjZWQ2OTU4NDk) I am at the last part, page 17 and I am quite confuse about the identifier for text box.

Lets say for example I create a button and 3 textbox. What will it do is when I click the button it will add the value from 1st textbox input and 2nd textbox input and display the result in 3rd textbox

This is confusing because I don't know how to specifically Identify each textbox so that I can specifically add the text box and display the result.

What I mean is, how is the button suppose to know that i am going to add the value from first textbox and second textbox and display in third textbox? because they have the same ID `EditID`

Should I Name the other textbox as EditID2, EditID3? 
The author also said that I need to declare `EditID` as constant as long as it will not have the same ID with other controls.

This is the code:

```
.if uMsg == WM_DESTROY
    invoke PostQuitMessage, 0

.elseif uMsg == WM_CREATE

    //Create Buttoon for Addition

    invoke CreateWindowEx, NULL, addr ButtonClassName, addr ButtonAdd, WS_CHILD or WS_VISIBLE or BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON, 225, 10, 120, 30, hWnd, ButtonID, hInstance, NULL
    mov hButton, eax




    //Create 3 TextBox. First text box for 1st input, Second TextBox for 2nd input, 3rd TextBox to show the result from added First textBox and Second texbox value 

    invoke CreateWindowEx, WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, addr EditClassName, NULL, WS_CHILD or WS_VISIBLE, 10, 10, 120, 30, hWnd, EditID, hInstance, NULL
    mov hEdit, eax
    invoke CreateWindowEx, WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, addr EditClassName, NULL, WS_CHILD or WS_VISIBLE, 10, 50, 120, 30, hWnd, EditID, hInstance, NULL
    mov hEdit, eax
    invoke CreateWindowEx, WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, addr EditClassName, NULL, WS_CHILD or WS_VISIBLE, 10, 110, 120, 30, hWnd, EditID, hInstance, NULL
    mov hEdit, eax

.elseif uMsg == WM_COMMAND   
    mov eax, wParam
        .if eax == ButtonID  // Here when add button add is click it will perform the add operation.
             shr eax, 16
            .if ax == BN_CLICKED
                    //code here to perform operations when click.

                .endif
        .endif

.else
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused too as there is no page 17 in the pdf you linked.  I think you meant page 15.
The code you posted however is nothing that the author wrote or intended to sell as an example code, it's your production.
As the author explicitly says

> It doesn't matter what they are as long as they don't have the same ID as any other control.

---

The *primary way* way to get "*references*" to controls within the WinAPI is the use of the *HWND* value returned by `CreateWindowEx`.
Every API that interacts with child windows use this *HWND* value to identify the objects in question.

The problem with *HWND* values however is that they are not fixed, they are known only at runtime, once your program is running and may change at every run.
This makes programming with visual tools and [DialogBoxes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632588(v=vs.85).aspx) harder as in these situation you don't explicitly have each control *HWND*.
To compensate thisWindows let you give each child window an id, this id is fixed, known at compile time and let you identify the control.
So these ids are a *secondary way* to reference controls and are mostly used with dialog box related API like `GetDlgItem` and during notification like *EN_CHANGE*.
Clearly duplicated ids make these APIs useless.

You are not using dialogboxes so having unique ids it is not necessary, even having the ids their selves is useless, you can pass 0 as the `hMenu` parameter of `CreateWindowEx` to not assign an id.

---

In your code you are storing all the *HWND* of the three textboxs in the same variable, thereby losing reference to the first two.
You can either:

1. Give each control an unique id, not store any *HWND* returned value and reference the controls by their ids (this may require more work with some API).
2. Save each *HWND* of the controls and use them.
3. Do both things

A possible code that assign unique ids an save each  *HWND* is

```
invoke CreateWindowEx, WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, addr EditClassName, NULL, WS_CHILD or WS_VISIBLE, 10, 10, 120, 30, hWnd, EditIn1ID, hInstance, NULL
mov DWORD PTR [hEditIn1], eax
invoke CreateWindowEx, WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, addr EditClassName, NULL, WS_CHILD or WS_VISIBLE, 10, 50, 120, 30, hWnd, EditIn2ID, hInstance, NULL
mov DWORD PTR [hEditIn2], eax
invoke CreateWindowEx, WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, addr EditClassName, NULL, WS_CHILD or WS_VISIBLE, 10, 110, 120, 30, hWnd, EditOutID, hInstance, NULL
mov DWORD PTR [hEditOut], eax
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try to work on your advice, I hope I can get it done.